# How to solve this beautiful integral equation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> **Question :** $f(x)$ is a continuous, positive function in $[0,a]$ and differentiable in $(0,a)$. If $f(x)$ satisfies $$\frac{1}{2} \int_0^x f^2(t)\mathrm dt=\frac{1}{x} \left(\int_0^x f(t)\mathrm dt\right)^2$$
>
> Then find $f(x)$

I tried to use Newton-Leibinitz's Integral rule to convert this equation into a differential equation.

This resulted in a complex differential equation, which is

$$\left(y'\right)^3x-3y\left(y'\right)^2-y''y^2=0$$

where $y=f(x)$
But I don't know how to solve this type of differential equation. I believe that there should be an alternative to solve this problem, can you please give me a hint on how to approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differentiating both sides in $x$ once, we get for $x\neq0$:
$$\frac{1}{2}f(x)^2 = -\frac{1}{x^2}\left(\int_0^xf(t)dt\right)^2+\frac{2}{x}f(x)\int_0^xf(t)dt\ .$$
Write $y(x):=\int_0^xf(t)dt$ and multiply both sides by $x^2$ to obtain
$$\frac{1}{2}x^2(y')^2=-y^2+2xyy'\ ,$$
which is equivalent to
$$0=\left(y-\left(2+\sqrt2\right)xy'\right)\left(y-\left(2-\sqrt2\right)xy'\right).$$
Thus, the equation is satisfied if, and only if
$$y=\underbrace{\left(2\pm\sqrt2\right)}_{=:\alpha_\pm}xy'\ .$$
It is easy to solve this to find that
$$y(x)=cx^{\frac{1}{\alpha_\pm}}$$
for some $c\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, and thus
$$f(x)=\pm\widetilde{c}x^{\frac{1}{\alpha_\pm}-1}$$
with $\tilde{c}\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, which solves the integral equation.

Comment: Thus it was correct with $x^\alpha$ but I go the incorrect values of $\alpha$ in my post.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Careful, I updated my answer: the $f(x)$ we find doesn't satisfy the integral equation, therefore the integral equation is not solvable. Do check my reasoning, I don't exclude possible errors.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Shouldn't it be $$y(x)=cx^{1/{\alpha}}$$

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}x^2(y')^2=-y^2+2xyy'$ is equivalent to $x^2(y')^2=-2y^2+4xyy'$ which can be written as $(xy' - 2y)^2 = 2y^2,$ so $xy' - 2y = \pm \sqrt2 y,$ i.e. $xy' = (2 \pm \sqrt2) y.$ The solutions of this are $y(x) = c x^{2 \pm \sqrt2}$ so $f(x) = (2 \pm \sqrt2) c x^{1 \pm \sqrt2} = \bar c x^{1 \pm \sqrt2}.$

Comment: @md2perpe Thanks, corrected.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud. But I agree with Jaideep; if $y = \alpha x y'$ then $y = c x^{1/\alpha}$.

Answer (score 0):

In the expression $\left(y'\right)^3x-3y\left(y'\right)^2-y''y^2$ all terms have the same degree of $y$ and the same degree of $x$. Therefore I assert $y = x^\alpha$ which gives
$$
\left(y'\right)^3x-3y\left(y'\right)^2-y''y^2 
= \left(\alpha x^{\alpha-1}\right)^3 x - 3 x^\alpha \left(\alpha x^{\alpha-1}\right)^2 - \alpha(\alpha-1)x^{\alpha-2}(x^{\alpha})^2 \\
= \alpha^3 x^{3\alpha-2} - 3 \alpha^2 x^{3\alpha-2} - \alpha(\alpha-1) x^{3\alpha-2} 
= \left( \alpha^3 - 3 \alpha^2 - \alpha(\alpha-1) \right) x^{3\alpha-2}
= \alpha \left( \alpha^2 - 4 \alpha + 1 \right) x^{3\alpha-2}
$$
This equals $0$ if $\alpha=0$ or $\alpha = 2 \pm \sqrt 3$.

I don't know if there are more solutions (EDIT: ... to the differential equation).

Comment: But $f(x)=x^0=1$ doesn't satisfy this equation.

Comment: @JaideepKhare. It does satisfy the differential equation, but obviously not the integral equation.

Answer (score 0):

The affirmation of the problem is false. Take $f(t)=t$, then:
$$\frac12\int_0^x f(t)^2dt=\frac12 \frac{x^3}{3},$$
and
$$\frac1x\left(\int_0^xf(t)dt\right)^2=\frac{x^3}{4}.$$
And $\frac12\int_0^x f(t)^2dt\neq \frac1x\left(\int_0^xf(t)dt\right)^2$.

I think that the problem can be reformulated (to be correct) as follows:

Let $F(s)=\int_0^sf(r)dr$, where $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Probe that:
$$\int_0^xf(s)F(s)ds=\frac12\left(\int_0^xf(s)ds\right)^2.$$

Comment: Sorry, I had formatted my question incompletely earlier, please see my edit now. We have to find $f(x)$ which satisfies this equation.

Answer (score 0):

Led by earlier conclusions we assert $f(t) = c t^\alpha$. This makes
$$\mathrm{LHS} = \frac12 \int_0^x f(t)^2 \, dt = c^2 \frac12 \int_0^x t^{2\alpha} \, dt = c^2 \frac12 \frac{1}{2\alpha+1} x^{2\alpha+1}$$
$$\mathrm{RHS} = \frac1x \left( \int_0^x f(t) \, dt \right)^2 = c^2 \frac1x \left( \frac{1}{\alpha+1} x^{\alpha+1} \right)^2 = c^2 \frac{1}{(\alpha+1)^2} x^{2\alpha+1}$$

These are equal if $2(2\alpha+1) = (\alpha+1)^2$ which is true when $\alpha = 1 \pm \sqrt 2$. Thus we have $f(t) = c t^{1\pm\sqrt2}$ as solutions. This, however, doesn't exclude the possibility of other solutions.